# Multiple queries in one query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in a database with start and stop times for each day of the week for some staff in Mysql in the following way:

```
Agent     Day     Start     End
agent1    Mon     17:00     23:00
agent1    Tue     16:00     23:00
agent1    Wed     18:00     23:00
```

I need this to the displayed in the following way:

```
Agent       Mon              Tue           Wed
        start   stop    start   stop  start   stop
agent1  17:00   23:00   16:00   23:00 18:00   23:00
```

Is there a way to do this through a query? I was thinking of doing multiple queries in one query but I don't quite get it.

Comment: You only need 1 query for this. What do you have so far?

Comment: I was trying to do something like this for each day:
Select (select start_dt from schedules where day = 'Mon') as 'MonStart',
 (select end_dt from schedules where day = 'Mon') as 'EndStart';

Comment: what if there would be more agents, "agent2", "agent3" ?

Comment: Actually yes I do have several agents in this database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sue a lot of case

```
select agent,
      case day when 'Mon' then start end as start_mon,
      case day when 'Mon' then `end` end as end_mon, 
      case day when 'Tue' then start end as start_tue,
      case day when 'Tue' then `end` end as end_the,    
      case day when 'Wed' then start end as start_wed,
      case day when 'Wed' then `end` end as end_wed
 from your_table
```

for gettin the value on the same row of agent you can use a temp table and group bt

```
select agent, max(start_mon), max(end_mon), max(start_tue), max(end_tue), max(start_wed), max(end_web)
   from ( 
        select agent,
           case day when 'Mon' then start end as start_mon,
           case day when 'Mon' then `end` end as end_mon, 
           case day when 'Tue' then start end as start_tue,
           case day when 'Tue' then `end` end as end_the,    
           case day when 'Wed' then start end as start_wed,
           case day when 'Wed' then `end` end as end_wed
        from your_table ) as t
    group by agent;
```

Comment: This almost had it as it has the data separated by day but will first start with Mon then go with Tue and so on... is it possible to get this all in the same row for each agent?

Comment: This is perfect, just what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You only need one query where you get all the information in the right order. So first so order by agent and then by day.

As you cannot order the days alphabetically, you need for example a `CASE` statement to get the right order:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM `your_table`
ORDER BY
    `agent`,
    CASE
        WHEN `Day` = 'Mon' THEN 1
        WHEN `Day` = 'Tue' THEN 2
        ...
        WHEN `Day` = 'Sun' THEN 7
    END
```

Storing the day number instead of the text would make this a bit more efficient of course.

Then when you get all your rows, you keep track of the current agent and as soon as the agent changes, you add a new row.

Comment: Noted, I'll go agent and do some changes in order to have the days as numerics values.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the solution using `group_concat` function which will get all days for a certain agent with all needed respective time ranges:

```
SELECT Agent, group_concat(Day,' ', Start, '-', End separator '/') AS dayData 
FROM `schedules`
GROUP BY Agent
```

This will get resultset which will look like as follows:

```
Agent  | dayData    
-----------------------------    
agent1 | Mon 17:00-23:00/Tue 16:00-23:00/Wed 18:00-23:00
agent2 | .... ..
```

When the resultset is fetched on PHP side, you can easily process each row with `explode('/', $row['dayData'])` (getting an array of days with time ranges). Then, explode each item with `explode(" ", $day)`... and so on. After that, you can create a "beautiful" output using html `<table>`